# jQuery slide toggle not working properly

Tags: jquery

Created a side nav with toggle but it not pushing the text that is underneath it. I modified  the code that I found in http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/easy-toggle-jquery-tutorial/. 
I cannot modify the body content/tag or the jQuery version (It's a very closed system. However, I can modify the css with in script tags). It is doing what I wanted to do, however it is not pushing the text as it was on the original tutorial. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

//Hide (Collapse) the toggle containers on load
$("#linkListSub3 li ul").hide(); 

//Switch the "Open" and "Close" state per click then slide up/down (depending on open/close state)
$("#linkListSub3 li").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    $("ul",this).slideToggle("slow");

    return false; //Prevent the browser jump to the link anchor
});
});
</script>


<style type="text/css">

body {
background-color:#333;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

ul{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

li{
margin:0;
padding:0;
list-style:none;
}


#linkList3{
background-color:#4f90b0;
width:200px;
padding:10px;
}

#linkListSub3 li {
height: 35px;
line-height: 35px;
width: 200px;
font-size: .9em;
font-weight: normal;
float: left;
}

#linkListSub3 li a {
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
}

#linkListSub3 li a:hover {
color: #ccc;
}

#linkListSub3 li.active {
background-color:#444;

} 

#linkListSub3 li a.submenu {

border-top: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
background-color:#444;
overflow: hidden;
font-size: .8em;
width:200px;
clear: both;
} 

</style>

</head>


<body>
<div id="linkList3" style="width: 200px; height: 1000px; ">
<div id="linkListSub3" style="width: 200px;">

<ul style="width: 200px">
  <li id="id-30683"><a href="/Section.aspx?id=31" target="_self"><span id="navArrow">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>About</a>
    <ul style="margin-left:0px;">
      <li id="id-30692"><a href="/Section.aspx?id=31" class="submenu" target="_self">About Us</a></li>
      <li id="id-30693"><a href="/what-we-do.aspx" class="submenu" target="_self">What We Do</a></li>

    </ul>
  </li>


  <li id="id-30684"><a href="/Section.aspx?id=2820" target="_self"><span id="navArrow">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>Social Justice</a>
    <ul style="margin-left:0px;">
      <li id="id-30699"><a href="/Section.aspx?id=2820" class="submenu" target="_self">Overview</a></li>
      <li id="id-30700"><a href="/page.aspx?id=222013" class="submenu" target="_self">Economic Response</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>



</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you clipped it short but the code you posted is missing the closing body and html tags, `</body></html>` as well as the doctype, opening html and head tags, `<html><head>`.

Comment: [Here is a JSFiddle of the OP's code](http://jsfiddle.net/gPxbn/1/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your parent `li` tags have a height specified in the CSS. When the child `ul` tags slide out, the parent cannot expand further than the specified height. Getting rid of the height in the CSS solves this issue.

Here is the updated JSFiddle without a height - http://jsfiddle.net/gPxbn/2/

Comment: Hi Connell, 

Thanks for the quick response. I tried the css but don't work. Isn't the z-index suppose to play with the layers. Just wanna make sure I explained myself clearly, I wanted the expanding element push the content further down, not expand over it. I also tried putting another <P> tags before and after div and still not working. seems like the slideToggle only works with div!!

Comment: Aha, yes I edited the answer just before your first comment when I realised that I misunderstood the question. You're welcome!

Comment: Hi Connell,

I was wondering you know the answer. The toggle is working but it is not smooth. It shows few lines and jumps to the last one. Any idea what might be causing it?  Codes on
http://jsfiddle.net/rexonms/FyHH5/

Thanks in advance,
Rex

Comment: @rex I'm having this same problem with my website atm. I think it's a bug in jQuery and unfortunately, I don't know of a workaround, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#linkListSub3 li").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    $("ul",this).slideToggle("slow"); // is this line correct?
    $(this).slideToggle("slow"); //should it be like this?
    return false; //Prevent the browser jump to the link anchor
});
```

Comment: That doesn't work... I just tried it in a JSFiddle.  AFAIK, you can use multiple selectors like that.

Comment: $("ul",this).slideToggle("slow"); // is this line correct? Yes this is correct because I want to toggle the UL element that is next to .this element.